# Reset timer after event in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am implementing logout after 15 mins idle session without using 3rd party lib or ngrx.
I have created a service:

```
run(){
    window.onload = () => {this.startTimer()};
    window.onmousemove = () => {this.resetTimer()};
}

startTimer(){
    let ticks = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
    return ticks
}
resetTimer(){
    // code here
}

sessionTimeOut(){
    // logic to logout
    this.resetTimer().subscribe(val =>{console.log(val)}
}
```

I have create few approach using some `rxjs` functions, none of them has worked so far, Is it possible to get some help on `resetTimer()` method? thank you.

Comment: What happens if you make `ticks` globally available to the component and then in the `resetTimer` method call `this.ticks = Observable.timer(0, 1000)` and then just reference the variable `ticks` in your markup, or reference it where ever you need to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `switchMap` on your mousemove event to restart the timer, this route removes the need to keep up with the timer values and just plug 15000 in to set and forget.

```js
const newTimer = () => Rx.Observable.timer(3000);
const mouseMove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    .startWith("loaded")
    .throttleTime(250);
const logOut = mouseMove.switchMapTo(newTimer());

logOut.subscribe(() => console.log('logout'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>

move mouse around here to not log out
```

From the comments below requesting emits, I assumed to be every second, with the value resetting on `mousemove`.

```js
const mouseMove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
  .startWith("loaded")
  .throttleTime(250)
  .do(() => console.log("restart timer"));
const newTimer = () => {
  console.log("starting timer");
  return Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000);
};
const timer = mouseMove.switchMapTo(newTimer());

timer.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `switchMap` changed the from startTimer to newTimer but hasn't restarted the timer itself. does it make sense?

Comment: It will create a new timer observable on each mouse move. in the example i linked if you move your mouse into the window before the initial timer expires you can keep moving your mouse around, if you stop, the final timer will kick in.

Comment: You'd probably want to throttle/debounce the mouse move since it is creating a new timer on each move event.

Comment: Sorry not the functionality I was looking for. I just want to restart the timer and console log it and it see it restarts from 0 again after event

Comment: Hmm... OK, not sure why you need that value, but, I'm updating the answer above to emit every second (and not after a defined amount like the initial) and restart to 0 after mousemove.

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 7 and investigating the ngrx tools I could make this code which I put in a service as a method and used it in each of my components. Now to restart each time you change components, it is necessary to implement Ondestroy to be able to unsubscribe the observable and thus the count will start again for each component that enters. I hope it helps for future projects.

This is the service showing the service interval-session.service.ts

```
import { Subject, Observable, timer, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, switchMap  } from 'rxjs/operators';

subscription: Subscription;
private reset$ = new Subject();
timer$: Observable<any>;

intervalCloseSession(){
  this.timer$ = this.reset$.pipe(
    startWith(0),
    switchMap(() => timer(0, 1000))
  );
}

this.timer$.subscribe((i) => {
  console.log("timer", i)
}
```

(example.component.ts)
At the end of the component code we put the onDestroy

```
import { IntervalSessionService } from 'services/interval-session.service';

private intervalService: IntervalSessionService;

constructor() {
   this.intervalService = new IntervalSessionService(authService, broadcastService, 
   user);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.intervalService.intervalCloseSession();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.subscription) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I commented above but would this work:

```
ticks: any;
start: number;
stop: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.start = 0;
  this.stop = 1000;
}

run(){
    window.onload = () => {this.startTimer()};
    window.onmousemove = () => {this.resetTimer()};
}

startTimer(){
    this.ticks = Observable.timer(start, stop);
}
resetTimer(){
    // code here
    this.start = 0;
    this.stop = 1000;
}

sessionTimeOut(){
    // logic to logout
    this.ticks.subscribe(val =>{console.log(val)}
}
```

Comment: No problem, but I edited the answer above. Let me know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Still no difference. iif you could upvote the post, maybe somebody can come out with a solution