# RxJS timer reset

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have the following timer in my Angular app:

```
const sessionWarntime = this.config.sessionWarntime ? 
this.config.sessionWarntime * 1000 : 240000; // time before session end 
this.warntimer = timer(this.sessionTime - sessionWarntime);
this.warntimerSubscriber();
```

Here is the subscriber method code:

```
private warntimerSubscriber() {
this.warntimer.pipe(
  first()
).subscribe((res: number) => {
  if (res === 0) {
    // Time to session end in minutes
    const sessionWarntime = this.config.sessionWarntime ? 
    this.config.sessionWarntime : 240;
    const min = sessionWarntime / 60;
    this.sessionWarning.emit(min.toString());
  }
});
```

}

Now, I would like to reset this timer in case the user is active, but how can I do that? The following line would create a new timer:

```
 this.warntimer = timer(this.sessionTime - sessionWarntime);
```

Comment: I think that this is the way - instantiate new timer and your question looks like a duplicate of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563781/reset-timer-after-event-in-angular-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset timer after event in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47563781/reset-timer-after-event-in-angular-2)